# Is it possible to generalize the two view Sampson error to multiple view cases in computer vision?

Tags: computer-vision, geometry

In multiple view geometry of computer vision, there is a geometric error called `Sampson error` which is very useful in the nonlinear estimation of fundamental matrix.

Can this `Sampson error` be generalize to multiple view cases so as to use it for multiple focal tensor estimation?

Comment: You probably ought to link to a definition of the Sampson error or provide a definition here.

Comment: thank you. It seems from this link, there already exists an answer: http://like.silk.to/studymemo/SampsonError.pdf